# EncryptedData was not recognized, apache cxf with spring

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, spring-security, cxf, jax-ws

my error is this:

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Message part
> {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData was not recognized.
> (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

Which is due to setting properties for decoding ecrypted data. My issue is that I am having problems how to do that with apache cxf (Timestamp and Signature works ok).

Here is my part of code:

public WSS4JStaxInInterceptor wss4JStaxInInterceptor() throws Exception {

```
   WSSSecurityProperties inProperties = new WSSSecurityProperties();
   //inProperties.addAction(WSSConstants.USERNAMETOKEN);
   inProperties.addAction(WSSConstants.TIMESTAMP);
   inProperties.addAction(WSSConstants.SIGNATURE);
   inProperties.addAction(WSSConstants.ENCRYPTION);
   inProperties.setEncryptionUser("xxx");
   inProperties.loadDecryptionKeystore(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("\"C:\\\\Users\\\\miha_\\\\OneDrive\\\\Dokumenti\\\\Job\\\\Lj\\\\Spring\\\\demo\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\xxxx.jks"),"xxx".toCharArray());;
   inProperties.setMustUnderstand(false);
   inProperties.loadSignatureKeyStore(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("\"C:\\\\Users\\\\miha_\\\\OneDrive\\\\Dokumenti\\\\Job\\\\Lj\\\\Spring\\\\demo\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\xxxx.jks"),"xxx".toCharArray());
   inProperties.setSignatureUser("cbd");
   //inProperties.setSignatureVerificationCryptoProperties(wss4jInProperties());

   //inProperties.setUsernameTokenPasswordType(WSSConstants.UsernameTokenPasswordType.PASSWORD_DIGEST);
   inProperties.setCallbackHandler(new ClientKeystorePasswordCallback());

   WSS4JStaxInInterceptor wss4JStaxInInterceptor = new WSS4JStaxInInterceptor(inProperties);

   return  wss4JStaxInInterceptor;
```

}

So I define "loadDecryptionKeystore" in which I get keystore. But where do I define which certificate to take (with setEncryptionUser("xxx"); ?) and where password to access private key in certificate?
Should I define also something else, how ?

ps.: this is configuration for server part when receiving request

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You define which certificate to take by calling `setEncryptionUser`.

The password for the private key should by supplied by the `CallbackHandler` that you define by calling `setCallbackHandler`. 
When the password for the private key will be needed, the framework will request it by calling the callback handler with an instance of `WSPasswordCallback` (see the documentation section about [WSPasswordCallback identifiers](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/topics.html#wspasswordcallback_identifiers) for details).

A simple example of a callback handler:

```
/**
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/gmazza/blog-samples/blob/master/cxf_x509_profile/client/src/main/java/client/ClientKeystorePasswordCallback.java">ClientKeystorePasswordCallback</a>
 */
public class ClientKeystorePasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

    private Map<String, String> passwords =
            new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ClientKeystorePasswordCallback() {
        passwords.put("myclientkey", "ckpass");
    }

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[i];

            String pass = passwords.get(pc.getIdentifier());
            if (pass != null) {
                pc.setPassword(pass);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have set as you suggested but still, the main issue is that callback is not triggered (i have put some logging in it), why I am unable to find out.  I have put eveything in pastebin, also pom part if there is something wrong. here is pastebin where I have put everything: https://pastebin.com/uEA3PWvK Thank you so much!

Comment: Another thing, if i define   "public WSS4JStaxInInterceptor wss4JStaxInInterceptor() throws Exception {}" as @Bean i get error:https://pastebin.com/TrHgVsqj

Comment: Regarding the error - the error log indicates that a `NullPointerException` occurs when the method `wss4JStaxInInterceptor` is called. As the error log does not contain any more details, I can't tell you more. You'll have to debug that method to find the line that causes it and fix it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the main issue was the path to the keystore, which i have fixed and now the callback is triggered. The main issue is now that i get error: " Error reading XMLStreamReader: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: A security error was encountered when verifying the message"  here is also pastbin:https://pastebin.com/kBDT3XB6 Is there any way to debug this. I am using the same certificates on spring with wss4j and there it is working (but i have issue with soap action).